# Does the $C^1$ norm for the boundary of a ball depend on the radius?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Does the $C^1$ norm for the boundary of a ball with radius $r$ depends on the radius $r$?

I use the classical definition of the $C^k$ boundary of a bounded domain: $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$. We say that the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is $C^k$ (or $\Omega$ is $C^k$) if for any $x\in \partial\Omega$, there exists an open neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ of $x$, an open set $V\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and a $C^k$ diffeomorphism $\phi:~U\to V$ such that $$ \phi(U\cap \Omega)=V\cap \{y_n>0\},\quad \phi(U\cap \partial \Omega)=V\cap \{y_n=0\}. $$

The C^1 norm of the boundary is defined by the sum of the C^1 norms of such diffeomorphisms over the neighborhoods that cover the whole boundary.

Comment: Depends on how you define the norm. Please clarify.

Comment: Here is the classical definition of the C^k boundary of a bounded domain: $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\R^d$ and $k\in \N$. We say that the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is $C^k$ (or $\Omega$ is $C^k$) if for any $x\in \partial\Omega$, there exists an open neighborhood $U\subset \R^d$ of $x$, an open set $V\subset \R^d$ and a $C^k$ diffeomorphism $\phi:~U\to V$ such that
$$
\phi(U\cap \Omega)=V\cap \{y_n>0\},\quad \phi(U\cap \d \O)=V\cap \{y_n=0\}.
$$

Comment: Added information should be in the post, not in a comment. I edited in it. However, you did not answer my question: how is the $C^1$ *norm* of a function defined?